# Trouble adding duplicates to a closed question

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, dupehammer, close-dialog

Found a JavaScript bug when using the hammer. Steps to reproduce:

1. Close a question as duplicate (or find an existing one)
2. Edit the list of duplicate targets
3. Click the link to add a new duplicate target
4. Click on one of the pre-filled questions

Nothing happens, unless you click on the title, which acts as a normal link.

By searching for a target, it can be made to work – just the pre-selected options don't respond to click events like they should.

Comment: *Found a Javascript bug* ... well, that is why the book about *The Bad Parts* has so many pages ...

Comment: it's a feature: the pre-selected options never works so you never have to select them ;)

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. I found it a couple of weeks ago, but every time I see I forget to raise a bug about it.

Comment: I forgot about it and repeated it on [Duplicate selection doesn't allow to pick an item without searching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383429/515960)

Comment: @Dharman yeah I should have posted this on MSE as it's almost certainly a network-wide issue

Comment: I have reproduced this bug as well. As a workaround: it is possible to *drag* the link into the text field at the top.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Posting this here because this one is [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)ed, hopefully it helps whoever handles the ticket.

It appears that in [duplicate-targets-edited](https://cdn-dev.sstatic.net/Js/duplicate-targets-edited.en.js?v=2b6b86a05687) they've forgotten to provide a callback to `asyncLoad` which would normally handle making the originals clickable:

This is the current code:

```javascript
addButton.click(function (e) {

    addButton.loadPopup({
        url: '/questions/originals/' + questionId + '/find-originals-popup',
        target: $('.container')
    })
        .done(function ($popup) {
            StackExchange.vote_closingAndFlagging.close_initDuplicateSubPane();
            $popup.asyncLoad();
```

There should be a callback to `StackExchange.vote_closingAndFlagging.close_afterLoadListOriginals` which is not currently being done:

```javascript
addButton.loadPopup({
    url: '/questions/originals/' + questionId + '/find-originals-popup',
    target: $('.container')
})
    .done(function ($popup) {
        StackExchange.vote_closingAndFlagging.close_initDuplicateSubPane();
        $popup.asyncLoad({
            callback: StackExchange.vote_closingAndFlagging.close_afterLoadListOriginals
        });
```

It *does* work elsewhere because when navigating to the duplicate closure window from the standard close dialogue the callback is appropriately attached in [full.en.js](https://cdn-dev.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js?v=edf11505d321)

```javascript
paneToShow
    .addClass('popup-active-pane')
    .show()
    .trigger('show')
    .asyncLoad({
        callback: closeAfterLoadListOriginals
    });
```

---

In the meantime, here's a simple UserScript that fixes the problem by simply overwriting the `duplicateTargetsEdited` with the fixed implementation:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Fix Edit Originals
// @version      0.0.1
//
// @match        *://*.stackoverflow.com/questions/originals/*/edit
//
// @run-at       document-start
//
// @grant        none
//
// ==/UserScript==
/* globals StackExchange */

(function () {
    'use strict';

    const overWriteWithFix = () => {
        Object.defineProperty(StackExchange, 'duplicateTargetsEdited', {
            get() {
                return function (questionId, questionUrl) {

                    var saveButton = $('.js-save-origs');
                    var addButton = $('.js-add-orig');
                    var list = $('.js-originals-list');

                    var countOriginals = function () {
                        return $('.js-originals-list .js-remove-orig').length;
                    };

                    var getOriginalIds = function () {
                        return list.find('.js-remove-orig').map(function (i, v) {
                            return $(v).data('id');
                        });
                    };

                    var updateButtons = function () {
                        var originalCount = countOriginals();
                        saveButton.enable(originalCount > 0 && originalCount <= 5);
                        addButton.enable(originalCount < 5);
                    };

                    addButton.click(function (e) {

                        addButton.loadPopup({
                            url: '/questions/originals/' + questionId + '/find-originals-popup',
                            target: $('.container')
                        })
                            .done(function ($popup) {
                                StackExchange.vote_closingAndFlagging.close_initDuplicateSubPane();
                                $popup.asyncLoad({
                                    callback: StackExchange.vote_closingAndFlagging.close_afterLoadListOriginals
                                });

                                $('#add-original-form').submit(function (ev) {
                                    ev.preventDefault();

                                    var newOriginal = parseInt($('.js-original-question-id').val(), 10);
                                    var existingOrigs = getOriginalIds();
                                    for (var i = 0; i < existingOrigs.length; i++) {
                                        if (existingOrigs[i] == newOriginal) {
                                            $popup.find('.js-add-original').showErrorMessage(__tr(["The selected question is already listed!"], undefined, "en", []), {
                                                relativeToBody: false,
                                                position: {at: 'left center', my: 'right top'},
                                                css: {'z-index': 10}
                                            });
                                            return;
                                        }
                                    }

                                    $.get('/questions/originals/get-original-row/' + newOriginal, function (html) {
                                        list.append(html);
                                    })
                                        .fail(function () {
                                            setTimeout(function () {
                                                addButton.showErrorMessage(__tr(["Error fetching question details. Please try again."], undefined, "en", []), {
                                                    relativeToBody: true,
                                                    position: {at: 'right center', my: 'left top'},
                                                    css: {'z-index': 10}
                                                });
                                            }, 0);
                                        })
                                        .always(function () {
                                            StackExchange.helpers.closePopups();
                                            updateButtons();
                                        });
                                });

                                // the short story here is that initialization doesn't complete until the "show" event is triggered.
                                // but we can't trigger that NOW, because the popup isn't actually visible yet
                                // popup gets faded in after this callback returns...
                                // so, spin the event loop and listen for animation completed after it has had time to start.
                                // all this for the sake of re-using the duplicate dialog logic unchanged
                                setTimeout(function () {
                                    $popup.promise().then(function () {
                                        $popup.find(".close-as-duplicate-pane").trigger("show");
                                    });
                                }, 0);
                            });

                        e.preventDefault();
                    });

                    list.on('click', '.js-remove-orig',
                        function (e) {
                            $(this).closest('.js-original-question').remove();
                            updateButtons();
                            e.preventDefault();
                        }
                    );

                    saveButton.click(function (e) {

                        var originals = getOriginalIds().toArray();

                        $.post('/questions/originals/' + questionId + '/save-originals', {
                            originalsIdsJson: JSON.stringify(originals),
                            fkey: StackExchange.options.user.fkey
                        }).done(
                            function () {
                                location.href = questionUrl;
                            }
                        ).fail(
                            function (response) {
                                saveButton.showErrorMessage(response.responseJSON, {
                                    relativeToBody: true,
                                    position: {at: 'right center', my: 'left top', css: {'z-index': 10}}
                                });
                            }
                        );

                        e.preventDefault();
                    });

                    var $sortable = $('.js-originals-list.sortable');
                    StackExchange.loadJqueryUi().done(function () {
                        $sortable
                            .sortable({
                                axis: "y",
                                update: function () {
                                    saveButton.enable();
                                }
                            });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }

    if (window.StackExchange === undefined || Object.keys(window.StackExchange).length === 0) {
        Object.defineProperty(window, 'StackExchange', {
            configurable: true,
            internalSE: undefined,
            get() {
                return this.internalSE;
            },
            set(newStackExchange) {
                if (Object.keys(newStackExchange).length !== 0) {
                    delete window.StackExchange;
                    window.StackExchange = newStackExchange;
                    overWriteWithFix();
                } else {
                    this.internalSE = newStackExchange;
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        overWriteWithFix();
    }
}());
```

Comment: This was indeed the solution, thank you. The fix is rolled out now.

Answer (score 6):

This is now fixed, as of Feb 6<sup>th</sup>, 2023.

You can now select one of the suggested duplicates, which loads the question into the popup box, then the "Add Original" button is enabled to confirm.